# Select id from table admin with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, authentication

i need help with php code trying to retrieve all information from a table using the username that is logged in.

So here is a example:

Bob logs in with his username & password
He then comes to a members only section
In this section it displays his results from the admin table which will show: username & password

Hope this makes sence, I am using a session()

Comment: you'll need to be more specific

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, no. Are you trying to build a secure system that lists other administrators?

Comment: have you worked with databases before? This is lacking a lot of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that hard to accomplish. You basically had the answer in your comment.

```
<?php
 $query = "select * from table_name where username = '". $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $password = $row['password']
 }
 // Then do your output of information
?>
```

Comment: I really didnt miss much :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question needs to be clearer.

retrieving all information from a table could mean doing

```
<?php $result= mysql_query("select * from table_name;") ?>
```

Comment: Yes i can do that simply, but i want to check my session() for the username logged in, then use that in a variable i.e. test & then find the username information in the database and display it, here it is in psudo code.

SESSION() - SAYS BOB IS LOGGED IN

VARIABLE $TEST ==SESSION LOGIN USERNAME

SELECT * FROM DATABASE_NAME WHERE Username == $TEST

THIS SHOULD THEN DISPLAY THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD OF BOB!